# Migration of Spring Security from 3.2.9 to 5.7.1

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm trying to migrate Spring Security from 3.2.9 to 5.7.1 and Spring framework from 3.2.13 to 5.3.20.

In the runtime, I'm getting the below errors.

No default constructor found;

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'basicAuth' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security.xml]: 
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 

Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter]: 

No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.<init>()
        at deployment.mycompany.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
        at deployment.mycompany.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1232)
        at deployment.mycompany.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
        at deployment.mycompany.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at deployment.mycompany.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at deployment.mycompany.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at deployment.mycompany.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at deployment.mycompany.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at deployment.mycompany.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
        ... 52 more
```

Below is the snippet of beans configuration:

```
 <beans:bean id="basicAuth" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter" >
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <beans:property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="basicAuthEntryPoint" />
    </beans:bean>
```

Tried to add a constructor initialization for authenticationEntryPoint. It's still not working.

```
 <beans:bean id="basicAuth" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter" >
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <beans:property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="basicAuthEntryPoint" />
        <beans:constructor-arg index="1" ref="basicAuthEntryPoint" />
    </beans:bean>
```

Appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved after I made the below changes.

I replaced the below configuration:

```
<b:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter">
    <b:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <b:property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="entryPoint"/>
</b:bean>
```

With this:

```
<b:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter">
    <b:constructor-arg ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <b:constructor-arg ref="entryPoint"/>
</b:bean>
```